# Build a quiz game with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, react.js, quiz, twitter-bootstrap

The task is to build a quiz game which has the following sections:

- Displaying a question
- Answer options
- Status of correct and incorrect answers so far

Expected functionality:

A question is displayed. The user clicks on one of the four shown answer options. Afterwards are either the correct or the incorrect answers incremented. The next question is shown.

[image: Screenshot of the GUI]

The game has to have at least 10 questions.

Here's my implementation:

```js
class QuestionPanel extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
 
  render() {
  
    if (this.props.activeGame) {
      return ( <div className="text-center">
                  <p className="question-panel">{ this.props.question }</p>
               </div> )
    } else {
      return ( <div className="text-center">
                 <p className="question-panel message">Game Over</p>
                 <div className="hyperlink-button">
                   <a onClick={ this.props.resetGame } href="#">Restart</a>
                 </div>
               </div>);
    }
  }
}

class Option extends React.Component { 
  render() {
    return <div><a href="#"
              onClick={ this.props.triggerProcess } 
              className="option-card">
            { this.props.optionValue }
           </a></div>;
  }
}

class StatusDisplay extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<div className="status-display text-center">
                  <p>Correct: { this.props.correct }</p>
                  <p>Incorrect: { this.props.incorrect }</p>
            </div>)
  }
}

class GameBoard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props); 
    
    this.processGuess = this.processGuess.bind(this);
    this.resetGame = this.resetGame.bind(this);
    
    this.state = {
      currentIndex: 0,
      correct: 0,
      incorrect: 0,
      activeGame: true,
      questionsAnswer: [
        { // 1
          question: 'What is 8 x 1 ?',
          options: [ 2, 7, 8, 9],
          answer: 8
        },
        { // 2
          question: 'What is 3 + 4 ?',
          options: [ 5, 7, 9, 34],
          answer: 7
        },
        { // 3
          question: 'What is 10 - 6 ?',
          options: [ 2, 4, 10, 7],
          answer: 4
        },
        { // 4
          question: 'What is 12 / 3 ?',
          options: [ 4, 6, 3, 8],
          answer: 4
        },
        { // 5
          question: 'What is 11 + 0 ?',
          options: [ 15, 11, 12, 10],
          answer: 11
        },
        { // 6
          question: 'What is 13 + 2 ?',
          options: [ 4, 17, 9, 15],
          answer: 15
        },
        { // 7
          question: 'What is 33 / 11 ?',
          options: [ 2, 3, 4, 1],
          answer: 3
        },
        { // 8
          question: 'What is 2 + 5 ?',
          options: [ 10, 7, 8, 6],
          answer: 7
        },
        { // 9
          question: 'What is 9 - 4 ?',
          options: [ 5, 7, 6, 9],
          answer: 5
        },
        { // 10
          question: 'What is 11 * 2 ?',
          options: [ 20, 22, 33, 34],
          answer: 22
        }
      ]
    };
  }
  
  resetGame() {
    this.setState({
      currentIndex: 0,
      correct: 0,
      incorrect: 0,
      activeGame: true
    });
  }
  
  processGuess(e) { 
    
   if (this.state.currentIndex + 1 === this.state.questionsAnswer.length) { 
       this.setState( { activeGame: false } );
     
       return;
   }
   // For accomplishing a better readible equality-check.
   let answer = parseInt(e.target.textContent);
   let correctAnswer = 
       parseInt(
          this.state.questionsAnswer[this.state.currentIndex]['answer']
        );
    
   if ( answer === correctAnswer ) {
       this.setState( {correct: this.state.correct + 1} );
   } else {
       this.setState( {incorrect: this.state.incorrect + 1} );
   } 
    
   this.setState( {currentIndex: this.state.currentIndex + 1} );
  }
  
  render() {
    var options = [];
    
    if (this.state.activeGame) {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.state
                              .questionsAnswer[0]
                              .options
                              .length; i++) {
        options.push( <Option optionValue={
                this
                  .state
                  .questionsAnswer[this.state.currentIndex]
                  .options[i] }
              triggerProcess = { this.processGuess } 
              activeGame = { this.state.activeGame } /> );
      }
    }
    
    return (  <div>
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="offset-lg-2 col-lg-7 col-md-12">
                      <QuestionPanel activeGame={ this.state.activeGame } 
                                     question={
                                        this
                                          .state
                                          .questionsAnswer[this.state.currentIndex]
                                          .question }
                                     resetGame = { this.resetGame } />
                      <div className={ this.state.activeGame 
                                        ? 'visible'
                                        : 'hidden' } >
                         { options }
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-12">
                      <StatusDisplay 
                        correct={ this.state.correct } 
                        incorrect={ this.state.incorrect } />
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div> );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <GameBoard className="game-board" />, 
                  document.getElementById('board') );
```

```css
body {
  font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
  background-color: rgba(150, 150, 150, .6);
}

.container {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.option-card {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(240, 240, 240, 1.0);
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
  color: rgba(20, 20, 20, 1.0);
}

.option-card:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0);
}

.option-card:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
  color: rgba(20, 20, 20, 1.0);
}

.question-panel {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: crimson;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.question-panel.message {
  color: blue;
}

.status-display {
  margin-top: 52px;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.hyperlink-button {
  text-align: center;
}

.hyperlink-button a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: 2px solid;
  color: #000;
  margin: 10px 0 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.hyperlink-button a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.hyperlink-button a:active {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="board" class="container"></div>
```

Working live-demo on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/mizech/pen/vJPLae/) !

For accomplishing responsive behavior I used Twitter Bootstrap.

It looks rather fine to me. But it has become a lot of code. I have seen solutions of others which were shorter.

Therefore my questions:

- Is my implementation done in a good way and fashion?
- Where could it be improved? Especially concerning brevity.

Looking forward to reading your hints and suggestions.

Comment: It's not exactly a guessing game though, is it? It's a quiz.

Comment: @Mast Well, yep. Quiz might have been better. Indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a couple of things you could simplify:

- Most of your components have no state, so they can be functional components, which are shorter and cleaner:

  ```
  function StatusDisplay(props) {
    return (
        <div> ...
    )
  }
  ```
- The `GameBoard` constructor can call `this.resetGame()` to avoid duplicating the setup logic.
- This:

  ```
  var options = [];

  if (this.state.activeGame) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state
                            .questionsAnswer[0]
                            .options
                            .length; i++) {
      options.push( <Option optionValue={
              this
                .state
                .questionsAnswer[this.state.currentIndex]
                .options[i] }
            triggerProcess = { this.processGuess } 
            activeGame = { this.state.activeGame } /> );
    }
  }
  ```

  can use `map`:

  ```
  let options = [];

  if (this.state.activeGame) {
      options = this.state.questionsAnswer[this.state.currentIndex].options.map(option => (
        <Option optionValue={ option }
                triggerProcess={ this.processGuess }
                activeGame={ this.state.activeGame } />
      ))
  }
  ```
- You could forgo one of {correct, incorrect, currentIndex}, since they're related by addition, but I think it's clearest to store all three as you currently do.
- Not a simplification, but: have you considered dynamically generating the questions and answers?

Comment: Thanks a lot. :) Implementing dynamic questions / answers would be an awesome enhancement indeed.